# How to bind an event to a treeview node in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I am currently making a treeview using Vuetify. What I am trying to do is that I want to bind an event whenever I click on a node. For example when I click on a certain node a dialog box will pop out to show the node's details. I want to know how to fire off an event on click.

Comment: The problem is that the @update:active event passes only the KEY of the clicked node and not the relative object

Comment: see `return-object` prop in documentation to change this behaviour

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vuetify's Treeview component provides a scoped slot *label* that you can use to change the content displayed for each node. For example, to open a dialog box, you could do something like this:

```
  <v-treeview
    v-model="tree"
    :items="items"
    activatable
    item-key="name">
    <template slot="label" slot-scope="{ item }">
      <a @click="openDialog(item)">{{ item.name }}</a>
    </template>
  </v-treeview>
```

You can then use a [dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#api) component and open it/change its contents using a openDialog method

Update 2022-04-01 the `slot="label" slot-scope` is deprecated. Here is an updated version:

```
  <v-treeview
    v-model="tree"
    :items="items"
    activatable
    item-key="name">
    <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
      <a @click="openDialog(item)">{{ item.name }}</a>
    </template>
  </v-treeview>
```

Comment: The only problem with this method is that you have to click exactly on the label for click event to trigger. I used the label slot but later found @update:active method which is perfect.

Comment: You can simply do this https://pastebin.com/CTYmYbvJ

You just need to do the clicked logic and selection state by your own but that should be easy then :)

Answer (score 9):

```
<v-treeview
    v-model="tree"
    :items="items"
    :active="active"
    activatable
    open-on-click
    @update:active="test"
    >
```

```js
methods: {
    test() {console.log('TEST', this.active)},
```

Answer (score 3):

You've two events :

The first one is [`update:open`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#events-update:open) that's fired when you click on a node that has child nodes and its handler has the opened node as parameter :

```
@update:open="openNode"
```

in methods :

```
methods:{
  openNode(node){
      //
   }

}
```

The second one is [`update:active`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-treeview/#events-update:active) that's fired when you click on a leaf that doesn't child nodes and its handler has the clicked node as parameter :

```
@update:active="clickOnNode"
```

in methods :

```
methods:{
  clickOnNode(node){
      //
   }

}
```

To get the node with its fields you should add the prop `return-object` :

```
 <treeview return-object @update:active="clickOnNode" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

@anthonio-achiduzu , At least for Vuetify version 2.3.3, the `@update:active` is triggered before the `this.active` being changed , so the `test()` will output a empty array in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

With Vuetify 2.3.5, I use this and it's ok

```
<v-treeview return-object item-key="id" hoverable activatable selected-color="red"
          @update:active="updateForm" color="warning" :items="categories">
</v-treeview>
      <template slot-scope="{ item }">
                <a @click="updateForm(item)">{{ item.name }}</a>
      </template>
```

In methods, i write funtion updateForm (but this is console to test value):

```
updateForm(item)
        {
            if(item.length>0)
                console.log(item[0].name)
        }
```